# Why does attach file upload feature not work properly when I'm seporate Logic and UI?

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I'm trying to separate UI and logic. But when I upload attach file, it doesn't work
It seems that some problem when they reload the page.
I deleted some codes which are not related to this issue.
And if you couldn't understand, just let me know

This is the main UI component.

```
const WriteNewInform = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  const {
    title,
    handleTitle,

    isMajor,
    handleIsMajor,

    attachFile,

    deleteAttachFile,
    handleAttachFile
  } = useInform()

  return (
    <S.WriteNewInformForm onSubmit={(e)=>{onsubmit(e)}}>
      <S.WriteNewInformLayout>
        <S.WriteNewInformContent>
          <S.InformIconBox>
            <InformIcon />
          </S.InformIconBox>

          <S.UploadBtnsWrapper>
            <ImgUpload/>

            <AttachFileUpload/> 
          </S.UploadBtnsWrapper>

        <S.InformContentForm className="contentRoot" id="contentRoot" contentEditable/>
        
        <AttachFileList/>
        </S.WriteNewInformContent>
      </S.WriteNewInformLayout>
    </S.WriteNewInformForm>
  )
}
```

Also, here's AttachFileUpload component

```
const AttachFileUpload = () => {  
    const {
      handleAttachFile,
    } = useInform()

    return (
        <>
            <S.UploadBtn for="attachFile">
              <S.UploadBtnIconBox>
                <InformAttachIcon />
              </S.UploadBtnIconBox>
              <S.UploadInputTxt></S.UploadInputTxt>
            </S.UploadBtn>
            <S.DisableInput type="file" id="attachFile" onChange={(e)=>{handleAttachFile(e)}}/>   
        </>
    );
};
```

And this is AttachFileList component

```
const AttachFileList = () => {
    const {
        deleteAttachFile,
        attachFile,
    } = useInform()

    return (
        <>
        {
          (attachFile.length > 0) &&
            <S.AttachedfileLayout>
              <S.AttachedfileBoxWrapper>
                <S.AttachedfileTitle></S.AttachedfileTitle>
                {
                  attachFile.map((file,idx) => (
                    <S.AttachedfileBox key={file}>
                      <S.AttachedfileLeftSideBox>
                        <S.FolderIcon/>
                        <S.AttachedfileBoxText>{file.name}</S.AttachedfileBoxText>
                      </S.AttachedfileLeftSideBox>
                      <S.CancleIcon onClick={()=>{deleteAttachFile(idx)}}/>
                    </S.AttachedfileBox>
                  ))
                }
              </S.AttachedfileBoxWrapper>
            </S.AttachedfileLayout>
        }
        </>
    );
};
```

Lastly, this is my custom hooks

```
const useInform = () => {
    const [attachFile,setAttachFile] = useState<File[]>([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        setAttachFile([])
    },[])

    const handleAttachFile = (e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if(e.target.files !== null){
            setAttachFile((prev)=>[ ...prev, e.target.files[0] ])
        }
    }
    
    const deleteAttachFile = (idx:number) => {
        setAttachFile((prev)=>{
            return prev.filter((file,fileIdx) =>  fileIdx !== idx)
        })
    }

    return {
        handleAttachFile,
        deleteAttachFile,
        attachFile,
        setAttachFile,
    }

};
```

I tried just separate logic and UI without dividing sub UI components such as AttachFileUpload and AttachFileList. And it worked. And I thought that do they re-render the page that call hooks, but I'm not sure.